# Wildfly 26.1.3 Domain Batch JBeret WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address

Tags: wildfly, batch-processing, jsr352, jberet, wildfly-26

I am trying to run JBeret Batch on a Wildfly Domain Cluster locally, but I keep getting the error

`"WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [ (\"deployment\" => \"ExampleJob.war\"), (\"subsystem\" => \"batch-jberet\") ]"`

To host the cluster I tried to use the default configuration. I am using Wildfly 26.1.3 .
To run my setup I am using this commands on my windows machine to run the Master and Slave.

```
.\bin\domain.bat  --host-config=host-master.xml -Djboss.domain.base.dir=domain1
and
.\bin\domain.bat --host-config=host-slave.xml -Djboss.domain.base.dir=host1 -Djboss.domain.master.address=127.0.0.1 -Djboss.management.http.port=9991
```

After That I deploy any batch application and try to run it in the adminpanel and get the error.

I tried also to use the cli, which didnt change anything.

I also tried to run it without the base.dir config so it uses the same folder but that did not change something.
I also tried to run different JDKs (I am now using JDK11).

To test that it is not working I tried [this job](https://github.com/jberet/jberet-wildfly-samples/tree/master/clusterInfinispan) from jberet directly. Also I tried other example Jobs like csv2json and keep getting the same error.

In Standalone the example jobs work.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. I'll take a look. Do you see the same error when deploying and running non-batch applications with the same configuration and steps?

Comment: No, deploying and running non-batch applications with the same configuration works. To confirm this I deployed examples from: https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart (greeter, helloworld) which work both fine. I also tried to use the batch-processing example from there and get the same error on the admin panel. But in this example there is an accompanying Webpage (127.0.0.1:8230/batch-processing/batch.jsf) and if I start it there it works. But using samples from you directly like for e.g cvs2json it does not work with the restAPI (localhost:8230/csv2json/api).

Answer (score 0):

When I ran $JBOSS_HOME/bin/domaon.sh with default configuration, which starts 2 server groups including 3 server instances, and deploy a batch application, and I was able to run the batch job from admin console, or cli.

```bash
> $JBOSS_HOME/bin/domaon.sh
```

Does that work for you?